# Do you have to run `npm install` everytime?

Tags: javascript

I am setting up a NativeScript environment on my computer for developing android apps with Angular. My question is, do I have to run `npm install -g nativescript` everytime after I sit down to work on my projects in the future? Or you just install it once and for all?

Comment: You've to install the package just once.

Comment: So... it seems someone is downvoting this question and every single answer to it. Huh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-g` flag tells `npm` to install `nativescript` (**g**)lobally. So it actually becomes accessible from the command-line in all of your projects. Don't worry, just remember to keep it updated by running `npm update -g` every once in a while. :)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You just install it once and for all.

You installed the package globally (using the `-g` flag) so you do not have to install it again and it will now be accessible from anywhere using the same commands.

If you had not used the `-g` flag, `nativescript` would only have been installed in that directory and you would have to install it in each directory you wished to use it.